# velocity, mass and force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, velocity

Is there an equation linking velocity, mass and force? I want to find the maximum force that an object of any given mass could exert. Assuming, the object with the given velocity stops dead in an instant, I thought of using F=ma but there is no time frame for the slowing down of the object since it's instant. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change in momentum $\Delta m v$ is equal to impulse $F \Delta t$, the force multiplied with the time that force acts on the body.

So to stop in an instant, the force is very large.